# symbol not found of method

Tags: java, symbols

I am doing this Java assignment for class, and for some reason this method keeps saying the symbol can not be found. The block of code below is what gave me the error. Not entirely sure as to why because I followed the book verbatim and there was no mention of it compiling with an error (usually there is an indication to look for that)

I added the rest of the assignment to the post. I wasnt sure if it was relative or not because I was getting the error before I wrote the second half of this that is being posted now. I'm not sure if the error has to do with calling the methods before the method is actually defined, but i tried switching the order and it did not make a difference when I compiled it.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class CreateFilesBasedOnState
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Path inStateFile = Paths.get("InStateCusts.txt");
        Path outOfStateFile = Paths.get("OutofStateCusts.txt");

        final String ID_FORMAT = "000";
        final String NAME_FORMAT = "    ";
        final int NAME_LENGTH = NAME_FORMAT.length();
        final String HOME_STATE = "WI";
        final String BALANCE_FORMAT = "0000.00";
        String delimiter = ",";

        String s =   ID_FORMAT + delimiter + NAME_FORMAT + delimiter
                   + HOME_STATE + delimiter + BALANCE_FORMAT
                   + System.getProperty("line.seperator");

        final int RECSIZE = s.length();

        FileChannel fcIn = null;
        FileChannel fcOut = null;
        String idString;
        int id;
        String name;
        String state;
        double balance;
        final String QUIT = "999";

        createEmptyFile(inStateFile, s);
        createEmptyFile(outOfStateFile, s);
        try
        {
            fcIn = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(inStateFile,
                                                      CREATE,
                                                      WRITE);

            fcOut = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(outOfStateFile,
                                                       CREATE,
                                                       WRITE);

            System.out.print("Enter customer account number >> ");
            idString = input.nextLine();
            while (!(idString.equals(QUIT)))
            {
                id = Integer.parseInt(idString);

                System.out.print("Enter name for customer >> ");
                name = input.nextLine();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
                name = sb.toString();

                System.out.print("Enter state >> ");
                state = input.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Enter balance >> ");
                balance = input.nextDouble();
                input.nextLine();
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(BALANCE_FORMAT);

                s =   idString + delimiter + name + delimiter + state
                    + delimiter + df.format(balance)
                    + System.getProperty("line.separator");

                byte[] data = s.getBytes();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

                if (state.equals(HOME_STATE))
                {
                    fcIn.position(id * RECSIZE);
                    fcIn.write(buffer);
                }
                else
                {
                    fcOut.position(id * RECSIZE);
                    fcOut.write(buffer);
                }

                System.out.print(  "Ener next cusomter account number or "
                                 + QUIT + " to quit >> ");

                idString = input.nextLine();
            }
            fcIn.close();
            fcOut.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error message: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void createEmtpyFile(Path file, String s)
    {
        final int NUMRECS = 1000;

        try
        {
            OutputStream outputStr
                = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file
                                                                 , CREATE));

            BufferedWriter writer
                = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStr));

            for (int count = 0; count < NUMRECS; ++count) {
                writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
            }
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error message: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, there is code missing.

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: I apologize. I am not understanding how it is not formatted correctly. And the exact error message is: CreateFilesBasedOnState.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
      createEmptyFile(inStateFile, s);
      ^
  symbol:   method createEmptyFile(Path,String)
  location: class CreateFilesBasedOnState

Comment: The code snippet you posted is still incomplete. I took care of the format issue. Please post your whole code.

Comment: Updated the code to include the rest of the assignment

Comment: The problem is a simple typo (`createEmptyFile` vs. `createEmtpyFile`). I flagged this question for being closed as "off-topic" (since it was a simple typo). Why it was not closed is beyond me.